# Requirement of facebookSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I would like to know what are the requirements using facebookSDK? I ask this because I can't share my photo in my app to my facebook. I already try the sample file that added from SDK like Scrumptious. I successfully setup the appid, version and display name in my plist, but failed many times to share it my photo. My xcode version is 6.1.1. I used IOS 8.0. Can you give me idea on how to use this developer.facebook.com. They have roles. I will be glad if you have tutorial on how to work the roles of facebook. I used new version of facebookSDK. Hoping for your help here.

Comment: Facebook SDK for iOS - Getting Started --> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Comment: I'm done that already, I can only post a message and a photo with  FBSDKShareLinkContent added. but sharing photo using this  FBSDKSharePhotoContent, no luck until now

Answer (score 1):

Follow these three steps

1.Create a key called FacebookAppID with a string value, and add the app ID there.

2.Create a key called FacebookDisplayName with a string value, and add the Display Name you configured in the App Dashboard.

3.Create an array key called URL types with a single array sub-item called URL Schemes. Give this a single item with your app ID prefixed with fb

Refere attched screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY0Tq.png)

Comment: sorry for late reply. I did these already, but nothing happen when I share my photo.